# Make unnecessarily recompiles a target

Tags: compilation, makefile

Firstly, here's my Makefile, it's really, really cool. 
It generates an executable for every 'c' file in the current directory.
Trivial with shell, PITA with Make... Did I mention, I haven't 'c'd in a decade so please don't laugh...

```
CC = gcc
#List all 'c' files by wildcard.
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
#Get the 'exe' equivalent of said file
EXECUTABLES=$(SOURCES:%.c=%)

#For each of the '*.exe' files
#append a 'c' suffix to the target
build: $(EXECUTABLES)
    $(CC) -c $(<:%=%.c) -o $<

clean:
    find ./ ! -name "*.c" -a ! -name "Makefile" -type f -delete

rebuild: clean build
```

Here are contents of my directory:

```
% ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:38 ./
drwx------ 94 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:38 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  990 2012-01-27 12:47 array_example.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  341 2012-01-27 13:38 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  430 2011-12-05 13:08 pointers.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  319 2012-01-27 12:45 should_create_warning.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1472 2011-12-19 16:16 socket-client.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1150 2011-12-19 16:15 socket-server.c
```

Now I run make

```
% make
gcc     array_example.c   -o array_example
gcc     pointers.c   -o pointers
gcc     should_create_warning.c   -o should_create_warning
gcc     socket-client.c   -o socket-client
gcc     socket-server.c   -o socket-server
gcc -c array_example.c -o array_example
```

Great, it re-compiled everything, the last line of output looked a bit inconsistent though.
How come it's different to the others?

```
% ls -la
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:38 ./
drwx------ 94 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:38 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1428 2012-01-27 13:38 array_example
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  990 2012-01-27 12:47 array_example.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  341 2012-01-27 13:38 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7164 2012-01-27 13:38 pointers*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  430 2011-12-05 13:08 pointers.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7139 2012-01-27 13:38 should_create_warning*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  319 2012-01-27 12:45 should_create_warning.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7515 2012-01-27 13:38 socket-client*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1472 2011-12-19 16:16 socket-client.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7579 2012-01-27 13:38 socket-server*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1150 2011-12-19 16:15 socket-server.c
```

I run make again, expecting it to NOP, after all, I haven't changed anything

```
% make
gcc -c array_example.c -o array_example
```

But it producted output, what gives ?

```
% ls -la
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:51 ./
drwx------ 94 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 13:51 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1428 2012-01-27 13:51 array_example
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  990 2012-01-27 12:47 array_example.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  341 2012-01-27 13:38 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7164 2012-01-27 13:38 pointers*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  430 2011-12-05 13:08 pointers.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7139 2012-01-27 13:38 should_create_warning*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  319 2012-01-27 12:45 should_create_warning.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7515 2012-01-27 13:38 socket-client*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1472 2011-12-19 16:16 socket-client.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yomom yomom 7579 2012-01-27 13:38 socket-server*
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1150 2011-12-19 16:15 socket-server.c
```

And it's re-compiled that array_example file, why always that one?

THE SOLUTION (Thanks to Eldar Abusalimov)

```
CC = gcc
#List all 'c' files by wildcard.
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
#Get the 'exe' equivalent of said file
EXECUTABLES=$(SOURCES:%.c=%)

all: $(EXECUTABLES)
.PHONY: all
$(EXECUTABLES): % : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY clean:
clean:
    find ./ ! -name "*.c" -a ! -name "Makefile" -type f -delete

rebuild: clean all
```

FINAL SESSION

Remove all generated files

```
% make clean 
find ./ ! -name "*.c" -a ! -name "Makefile" -type f -delete

% ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  2 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 18:07 ./
drwx------ 94 yomom yomom 4096 2012-01-27 18:07 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  990 2012-01-27 17:38 array_example.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  428 2012-01-27 17:38 array_of_pointers.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  274 2012-01-27 17:38 const_ptr.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  293 2012-01-27 17:38 function_pointers.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  313 2012-01-27 18:06 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  430 2012-01-27 17:38 pointers.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  228 2012-01-27 17:38 pointer_to_constant.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom  253 2012-01-27 17:38 pointer_to_pointer.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1472 2012-01-27 17:38 socket-client.c
-rw-r--r--  1 yomom yomom 1150 2012-01-27 17:38 socket-server.c
```

Run make again

```
% make
gcc -c array_example.c -o array_example
gcc -c array_of_pointers.c -o array_of_pointers
gcc -c const_ptr.c -o const_ptr
gcc -c function_pointers.c -o function_pointers
gcc -c pointers.c -o pointers
gcc -c pointer_to_constant.c -o pointer_to_constant
gcc -c pointer_to_pointer.c -o pointer_to_pointer
gcc -c socket-client.c -o socket-client
gcc -c socket-server.c -o socket-server
```

Now it doesn't do silly things anymore...

```
% make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the recipe of `build: $(EXECUTABLES)`. First, such rule is not supposed to create a `build` file. Second, and answering to your question about why only `array_example` is being always recompiled, `$(<:%=%.c)` results in the first listed prerequisite, which is likely to be the first one returned by `wildcard` (which sorts the result in the lexicographical order, not guaranteed, but [usually it does](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2010-07/msg00023.html)). That is,

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)# returns 'array_example.c pointers.c ...'.
EXECUTABLES=$(SOURCES:%.c=%)# is 'array_example pointers ...'.

build: $(EXECUTABLES)
# Here '$<' is the first item of '$(EXECUTABLES)', which is 'array_example'.
# And '$(<:%=%.c)' returns 'array_example.c'
    $(CC) -c $(<:%=%.c) -o $<
```

Finally, don't forget to add `.PHONY` target.

```
.PHONY: build
build: $(EXECUTABLES)
```

Make builds all programs listed in `$(EXECUTABLES)` using [an implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) to make executables from C sources. There is no need to specify anything else.

In case when the implicit rule is not OK, you can, however, override it, e.g. as follows:

```
$(EXECUTABLES) : % : %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure exactly what you meant but I've gotten there now, I don't want to use implicit stuff because I'm also going to compile a bunch of Tex and some ASM as well. Thanks Bro.

Comment: @BryanHunt, you're welcome, and I'm sorry if the reason of difficulties in understanding is my English. ;-)